# Broad question title, narrow question detail ... is this a problem?

Tags: discussion, beta

The question [What things should I consider when deciding if and when we should adopt?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/294/what-things-should-i-consider-when-deciding-if-and-when-we-should-adopt) is a massive question which deserves a prominent place in the site.

The question is well phrased and has already has one decent answer.

However, the question itself is very specific to do with a personal circumstance involving autism and an existing birth child, with some other personal issues. The answer addresses these issues.

So is it a problem if this question becomes the most prominent "Thinking about adoption?" question, when its details don't apply to most people who might be searching for adoption information?

If so, how to deal with it? I can't think of how to edit the title to reflect its specific concerns without turning the title into a monster. Nor of course is downvoting appropriate (which might be the solution if it were a bad question it its own right).

Comment: Did you do the exact same thing on this question on purpose, to prove the point? :-)

Comment: no, i meant it to be a general discussion, with the same issue easily applying to something else. say a general question title about "bullying" but then lots of detail in the question about a specific problem involving e.g. ethnicity.

Answer (score 5):

If the question is focused on some specific aspect that the title doesn't address, then we should edit the title to more accurately reflect the content folks will find when they click on it.

Comment: That's exactly what hawbsl wanted to, but editing the title to match would indeed make it huge. If you can solve it, go ahead!

Comment: Yeah, I scratched my head over how to write a short title for that one for a bit and failed to come up with anything either. But I answered in the spirit of the general case @hawbsl asked in the title here. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd let it be exactly as it is. Over time, more adoption questions will appear, and one of those may become the most prominent. Let's wait and see.

Comment: except that if i start a question about "thinking about adoption" from a more general point of view my question will be flagged a dupe.

Comment: @haw I don't think it will be flagged because the *content* is still different even though only the titles might be alike. Even if it gets flagged, a moderator would also catch many of such situations. I hope.